# sqlite database not support 2.1,2.2 version but 2.3 is supporting

Tags: android, sqlite

i implement this code for fatch database in my application but it supported only 2.3 version and above but do not supported 2.1,2.2 version
please tell me about the problem in my code  it is write or not

```
public class Help extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH ="/data/data/com.emobi.metro/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME ="mymetro";
    private final Context myContext;
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public Help(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);


    this.myContext = context;
}

    public void createDataBase(){
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(dbExist) {
            Log.e("test","createDatabase[] - db exists");
            this.getWritableDatabase();
        }else{
            Log.e("test","createDatabase[] - db not exists");
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
                Log.e("test","createDatabase[] - copied db");
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e("test","createDatabase[] - copied not db");
            }
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);


        }
    }



    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            Log.e("test","opened table");
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            Log.e("test","didn't open table - not exists");
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }



    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException,SQLiteException{
        Log.e("tofu","copy database");
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[myInput.available()];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLiteException, IOException{
        this.createDataBase();
        try { 
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.e("dbUpgrade","OLD Version = "+oldVersion+"");
    Log.e("dbUpgrade","New Version = "+newVersion+"");
    myContext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
    Log.e("dbUpgrade","deleted"+DB_NAME);
}
```

}

Thanks,

Comment: Any stacktrace? Error message? How do you know it is not supported?

Comment: What is the size of the database you are copying over? Is it more than 1mb?

Comment: yes my database is more then 1 mb its size is 4.4mb

Comment: no such table found error in versions less than 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Just change the database file .db extension in the asset folder  to .png or any other compressed format it will worke in 2.1, 2.2 and above devices